# How to select data from postgres sql on Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use rails db to enter db interface ,

type \d to list all tables.

but I can't select any data from table.

even i type the wrong command intentionally, it didn't show any errors?

any idea? Thanks

```
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        |   Type   | Owner
--------+-------------------+----------+-------
 public | books             | table    | poc
 public | books_id_seq      | sequence | poc
 public | carts             | table    | poc
 public | carts_id_seq      | sequence | poc
 public | line_items        | table    | poc
 public | line_items_id_seq | sequence | poc
 public | schema_migrations | table    | poc
 public | users             | table    | poc
 public | users_id_seq      | sequence | poc
(9 rows)

pnpbook_development-# select * from books
pnpbook_development-# select * frdasdaom dfdfoij
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add semicolon:

```
select * from books;
```